# HTML5 background video still not playing of Firefox

Tags: html, .htaccess, firefox, video, background

Sup guys.
Same issue here:
[HTML5 video not playing in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656465/html5-video-not-playing-in-firefox)
except my background video is still not showing after I added

**AddType video/ogg .ogv

AddType video/mp4 .mp4

AddType video/webm .webm**

to my .htaccess file I created in the same folder as my videos

This is the page its supposed to play in:
http://wearerocketscience.com/wordpress/contact/

Please help :)  TY

Answer (score 0):

I saw this answer at [Firefox won't play .webm and .ogv videos with HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822493/firefox-wont-play-webm-and-ogv-videos-with-html5)

Taken from Fez Vrasta:

> Seems I've found a solution:
>
> I switched my ogv codec from VP8 to Tehora and now Firefox can play
>   video correctly.
>
> I used this code for the source:
>
> The MIMEtype is:
>
> AddType video/ogg .ogv .ogg And the codec is:
>
> Xiph.org's Theora Video (theo) I guess it could work also for .webm
>   but I've not tested it.

Answer (score 0):

While the server seems to serve the correct mime types (webm and ogv play just fine when accessing directly) your `<source>` definitions are bogus:

```
<video id="video_background" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0">
    <source src="http://wearerocketscience.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/videos/contact.mp4"
      type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://wearerocketscience.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/videos/contact.webm"
      type="videos/webm">
    <source src="http://wearerocketscience.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/videos/contact.ogv"
      type="video/ogv">
 </video>
```

It is `video/webm` (not `videos`) and `video/ogg` (not `ogv`).